# Using a beta-binomial model to estimate the average for a uniform prior

Tags: self-study, bayesian, prior, uniform-distribution, beta-binomial-distribution

Say we had a sample of 100 people who were asked how many days during the last week they drove their car. Let's say the resulting frequency table is as follows:

Days, frequency

0, 1

1, 5

2, 3

3, 15

4, 20

5, 25

6, 31

7, 0

How do I go about using a **beta-binomial model for estimating the average number** of car-driven days a week for a **uniform prior**?

The data is binomial, with 7 Bernoulli trials each with a success probability of p.

I don't know how to proceed from here in terms of figuring out the average?

Thank you!

Comment: @Xi'an the data is binomial yes, with 7 Bernoulli trials each with a success probability of p.

Comment: @Xi'an yes I'm certain there are only 7.

Comment: @Xi'an not entirely sure what you are saying? bin(n, pi) ==> where "n" is the number of independent trials? So yes, there are 7.